# How do I install g++ on jenkins?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am very new to Jenkins, but given I see the following error:

```
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name
```

when trying to run a unittest with `cmake` on jenkins and

```
which g++
```

gives the error `Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`, I suppose `g++` is not installed on jenkins. How can I install it, or solve my problems in an other way?

I seem to have admin right on jenkins (I do not know how to find this out), but it was installed by someone else on a Linux server I cannot access.

Comment: Contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers here that suggest you install a single package. While this may work to provide for this specific error, I would suggest installing by group to ensure that you also have `make`, `automake`, `autoconf`, and etc.

On **RHEL5** (and derivatives);

```
sudo yum groupinstall development-tools
```

On **RHEL6** (and derivatives);

```
sudo yum groupinstall development
```

This said, `cmake` is an *optional component* of both of these groups and would still be installed separately if you need it. (`sudo yum install cmake`) Or, you can modify `/etc/yum.conf` to install optional packages with the groupinstall.

Add or change in `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
 group_package_types=default,mandatory,optional
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Jenkins server is the build server, simply have your system admin (if that's not you) install the g++ compiler. On Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora, this is the `gcc-g++` package. If the Jenkins server is not the build server, this package needs to be installed on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing compiler on the server where you want to compile Jenkins

```
 yum install gcc g++ -y
```

With the help of above commands you can install compiler and then you can try to compile
jenkins.